# Nginx as reverse proxy doesn't pass client host

Tags: nginx

I have Nginx server which works as reverse proxy for an nodejs app.

Nginx config example:

```
server {

  server_name www.example.com

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8796;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Currently when proxying requests $host variable or passed Host header always contains server_name value (domain of the server where nginx is started on).

This way req.headers['Host'] always has www.example.com value.

Can Nginx (used as reverse proxy in my case) pass proper request **client hostname** to the proxied application below (as Host header)?

Comment: I'm confused. What's a "client hostname"? Typically you get an IP address for the client, the agent, not much else.

Comment: With client hostname I mean on domain/subdomain from which the request was made

Comment: @Vlatko and what it should be for my smartphone (which is a client)?

Comment: @Alexey Ten probably nothing, in that case we can avoid passing proper host. Only in specific cases proper host is important to be passed, like when bot made request.

Comment: There is no concept of “client host” in http. You have IP address and User Agent. That’s pretty much all you could get

Comment: You can take the client IP and do a reverse DNS lookup on it in your app, but I doubt you'd get particularly consistent or useful information. What decision are you hoping to make based on this information?

Comment: @SmallClanger better precision and reliability in detection of particular bots

Answer (score 2):

You have missed to set the HTTP protocol version to 1.1 (default is HTTP/1.0) and your variable for the HTTP host name was wrong.

See fixed example below:

```
server {

  server_name www.example.com

  location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8796;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Comment: Jens thank you for your suggestion, but client info still isn't passed down.

Comment: Got it. But it doesn't make sense as you should see the client's real IP address in X-Real-IP or X-Forwarded-For.